# How does `moduleResolution` impact the type-correctness of enum comparisons?

Tags: typescript, typescript-module-resolution

I have a codebase that contains a union of types; each type has a `type` property that is the value of a string enum.

```js
enum Foo {
  Alpha: 'Alpha',
  Beta: 'Beta',
  // ... 27 other values
}

type Alpha {
  "type": Foo.Alpha,
  // ... stuff
}

type Beta {
  "type": Foo.Beta;
  // ... stuff
}

type Baz = Aplha | Beta // | ... etc
```

In a different module within the codebase, I have a function:

```js
const operateOnBaz = (baz: Baz) => {
  switch (baz.type) {
    case Foo.Alpha: //do stuff with Alpha
    case Foo.Beta: //do stuff with Beta
    // etc
  }
}
```

This was all working fine: no `tsc` errors, no `eslint` errors.

When I changed the `moduleResolution` from `NodeNext` to `Bundler` in the relevant `tsconfig.json` file, two things happened:

1. ESLint reports `The case statement does not have a shared enum type with the switch predicate`  on each case statement
2. TypeScript no longer discriminates the union within the case statements, leading to type errors.

I have tried switching to `if/else`s, but it's the same problem.

What I expected was that this code would not be dependent on the value of `moduleResolution.`

I know that I could switch from an enum to plain strings or something similar, but that's a lot of rework to do in lieu of actually understanding what is going on.

I'm looking to migrate from Node to Bun because of issues with how NodeJS handles named imports from CJS modules. Not doing that would also be an option.

Ultimately, I'm trying to understand how `moduleResolution` changes the behavior of enums and discriminated unions.